# can someone explain that what does the w1 and w2 and 4 mean in this query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Salary
FROM Worker W1
WHERE 4 = ( SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ( W2.Salary ) )
            FROM Worker W2
            WHERE W2.Salary >= W1.Salary);
```

Comment: These are table aliases -- abbreviations for the table reference -- and are a basic part of the SQL language.

Comment: Also, be aware that DISTINCT is not a function.